# sed command inserting text - bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am exploring sed function

what I have here is a simple text file shown below

Id,fruit name and quantity. now I want to add the amount of the fruit behind the quantity of each fruit respectively

fruit.txt

```
1,apple
2,banana
```

how to make it become like this.

expected output

first input of sed command

my textfile(fruit.txt) will become like this

```
1,apple,50
2,banana,40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed like this:

```
sed -i -r 's/(apple)(,[0-9]*)?$/\1,10/'

sed -i -r 's/(apple)(,[0-9]*)?$/\1,20/'

sed -i -r 's/(apple)(,[0-9]*)?$/\1,30/'
```

Comment: sorry to trouble you again but would you mind explaining like what is -r, s/ etc. I terribly bad at regex.  from what I know , **-i is inserting**,                                                 **/s(apple) means start from apple** and                           **(,[0-9*]) means begin with any number from 0-9 and matches anything behind it** . i'm not sure about the ?$/\1,30/ part

Comment: `-r` is for extended regex support in sed. `s/` is actually substitute command that does the replacement. `-i` is for inline editing of the file.

Answer (score 1):

use awk:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '/apple/{$3="whatever"}7' file
```

but if you don't have gnu awk 4.1, you have to do this to write back to the file:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '/apple/{$3="whatever"}7' file >~/foo.tmp && mv ~/foo.tmp file
```

Comment: What does `7` do? I'm assuming it writes back to the original file, like `sed -i` does. Where can I get the list of these numbers & their meaning?

Comment: @anishsane `7` (any non-zero number) does default awk action, which is `print`